# Help showing inductively defined sequence is monotone for $n \geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble proving the following sequence is monotone:

Let $a > 0$, $(s_n)$ be a sequence defined by:

$$s_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(s_n + \frac{a}{s_n}\right), \quad s_1 = a_0>0$$

I've been able to show the ratio of $\frac{s_3}{s_2} < \frac{1}{2}$, but I get the feeling that I'm headed down the wrong path once I try to show it's decreasing for a general $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that since all of your terms are nonnegative, we may apply the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality to get

$$ s_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} \left( s_n + \frac{a}{s_n} \right) \geq \sqrt{a} $$

for all $ n \geq 1 $, so that $ s_n \geq \sqrt{a} $ whenever $ n \geq 2 $. Then, we have that

$$ s_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} \left( s_n + \frac{a}{s_n} \right) \leq \frac{1}{2} (s_n + s_n) = s_n $$

establishing monotonicity of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This proof can be found in many places, for example in https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/newton-sqrt.pdf

In fact, this sequence is very classical, and it is important to know that, as it is decreasing and bounded by $0$ (all terms are $>0$), it converges to a limit $L$ such that  $L=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(L+\dfrac{a}{L}\right)$ a quadratic equation having for unique positive root $L=\sqrt{a}$.

The paper I have indicated calls it (rightly) the Babylonian method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots (it is a particular case of Newton's method).